# Why 29/8*100 will return 300 in C

Tags: c, calculation

The following is the code

```
    float lc = lcount/argc*100;
    return lc;
```

[image: This is the debug]

I tried to get 362.5 but the result is 300

Comment: What is the type of `lcount`? Please provide complete code as a [mre]. But likely it is an `int`. Which means `lcount/argc` is integer division with a result of 3. Try: `(float)lcount/argc*100`

Answer (score 0):

because initially it will computer division(because at the left of equation and having same precedence as multiplication )
lcount/argc(29/8=3)
and then multiplied by 100.
And at the last the computed result will be stored in floating format.

Your problem might be you are thinking initially it will compute 29/8=3.625
which wouldn't.